# Аналог функции arrayJoin в clickhouse на питоне

Tags: python, pandas

[image: рис 1]
[image: рис 2]

Есть массив - диапазон чисел(рис.1).Нужно развернуть строки по количеству чисел в диапазоне(рис.2). То есть нужно развернуть строки по столбцу weeks_visited

Comment: Используете pandas?

Comment: Не понимаю что значит "развернуть строки по столбцу weeks_visited", хотелось бы пояснение. Если  что в Pandas есть `pivot`, он разворачивает всякое, но так как вам надо или нет - не знаю.

Comment: @gil9red да это pandas

Comment: @CrazyElf там с рисунков все понятно, мне из одной строки нужно получить столько, сколько содержит диапазон указанного стьолбца

Comment: @CrazyElf то есть в первой строке столбцa есть список (0,1,2) мне нужно получить три строки 0
1
2

Comment: @ElenaBarbanova А, то есть из картинки 2 надо получить картинку 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `Pandas` есть для этого специальная функция: `explode`

Пример из [документации](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [[1, 2, 3], 'foo', [], [3, 4]], 'B': 1})
df
           A  B
0  [1, 2, 3]  1
1        foo  1
2         []  1
3     [3, 4]  1

df.explode('A')
     A  B
0    1  1
0    2  1
0    3  1
1  foo  1
2  NaN  1
3    3  1
3    4  1
```